# INSERT and DELETE data from database by clicking a link/button with ID USING MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-insert, sql-delete

I'm trying to `INSERT` and at the same time `DELETE` data from database. Whenever I view the info of a member by his ID in the URL, there will be a buttom/link with his info to ACCEPT that member. And if the admin click the ACCEPT button/link, that member will no longer be in the table of `requests` (and that's where DELETE should be done), and at the same time his details or data will be inserted in another table called "members". But when I click ACCEPT, it only echos the javascript for the confirmation, and when I click "Yes", nothing is happening, it just leads me back to the pendingRequests.php. I will share my code on here.

This is the **link** to be clicked to **view** the details of the member **from** the **pendingRequests.php**

```
<a href="/test/admin/view_request.php?view_id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >VIEW</a>
```

And this is where the data of the member will display: **view_requests.php**

```
<?php
    include ('dbcontroller.php');
    if(isset($_GET['view_id']))
    {
        $id=$_GET['view_id'];
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * from requests where id='$id'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    ?>  

    ID:     <?php echo  $row['id']; ?>

    <div class=" col-md-9 col-lg-9 "> 
        <table class="table table-user-information">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><h4><b>Profile Info</b></h4></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name:</td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?> <?php echo $row['MI']; ?> <?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email-address:</td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>

                </tr>
<tr>
                <td>Gender:</td>
                <td><?php echo $row['gender']; ?></td>

            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Status:</td>
                <td><?php echo $row['status']; ?></td>

            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td>Date of Birth:</td>
                <td><?php echo $row['bday']; ?></td>

            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Contact Number:</td>
                <td><?php echo $row['contactno']; ?></td>

            </tr>   

            <tr>
                <td><a href="javascript:view_id(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>) ">ACCEPT</a></td>
                <td>DECLINE</td>
            </tr>
<?php 
}
$conn->close();
?>
</tbody>
    </table>        

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function view_id(id)
    {
      if(confirm('Are you sure you want to accept this member request? '))
      {
        window.location='acceptRequest.php?view_id=='+view_id;

      }
    }
</script>
```

This is the **link/button** code where the admin clicks "**ACCEPT**" and the data of that member who owns that ID from "requests" table will delete and the info of the member will be inserted in the "members" table.

```
<a href="javascript:view_id(<?php echo $row['id']; ?>) ">ACCEPT</a>
```

And this is my **acceptRequest.php** code

```
<?php
include('dbcontroller.php');
if(isset($_GET['view_id']))
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM requests WHERE id=".$_GET['view_id'];

    $firstname = $row['firstname'];
    $MI = $row['MI'];       
    $lastname = $row['lastname'];  
    $gender = $row['gender'];
    $status = $row['status'];
    $maiden = $row['maiden'];
    $bday = $row['bday'];
    $contactno = $row['contactno'];
    $email = $row['email'];

    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO members(id,'$firstname','$MI','$lastname','$gender','$status','$bday','$contactno','$email')");

    mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM requests WHERE id=".$_GET['view_id']);
    header("Location: pendingrequests.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: according to this `window.location='acceptRequest.php?view_id=='+view_id;` the `view_id` parameter will always be empty

Comment: use "id" instead of "view_id" in your function.

Comment: I'm sorry, but why will it always be empty? @slash197

Comment: try `window.location='acceptRequest.php?view_id='+view_id;`

Comment: @louie because you have `==` instead of `=`

Comment: "view_id" is your function name.

Comment: you mean like this? @RahulVyas `function id(id)
 {
   
   if(confirm('Are you sure you want to accept this alumni request? '))
   {
    
   window.location='acceptAlumniRequest.php?view_id='+view_id;
   }
 }`

Comment: I mean to say -> function id(id) { if(confirm('Are you sure you want to accept this alumni request? ')) { window.location='acceptAlumniRequest.php?view_id='+id; } }

Comment: yea, sorry i didn't notice the double equal symbol. `window.location='acceptRequest.php?view_id='+view_id;` but still the same @user3284463

Comment: @louie try what @rahul Vyas said. try this:  `window.location='acceptRequest.php?view_id='+id;`

Comment: i did that, but when i click "accept" it doesn't echo the javascript for the confirmation anymore @RahulVyas

Comment: Hmm, check what error you get in your console.

Comment: i did this ->`function view_id(id)` and    `window.location='acceptRequest.php?view_id='+id;` and it finally deletes from the requests table BUT the data didn't insert in the members table. @RahulVyas

Comment: the data of the member from requests table finally deletes when i click the accept link, but it didn't insert in my members table. @user3284463

Comment: Assign your insert query to a variable like `$sql` and then make a statement `if($sql){ delete query...redirect}`

Comment: okay thank you sir, i will try that @user3284463

Comment: @louie Now is it inserting?

Comment: when i did this, both delete and insert query didn't workk @user3284463

Comment: @louie Yes, Only if the insert is succesful then it will delete. If insert is not successful it won't do the delete query

Comment: @louie Please post your table structure

Comment: @louie echo that $sql and copy that query and run directly in phpmyadmin, it will give you proper message.

Comment: i'm still trying to do this because i think this is the right way. @user3284463

Comment: Yay! It's working now! Thank you :D @user3284463

Comment: That is great! I know that feel of relief and excitement. Please select a best answer :) @louie

Comment: I'm trying to give a vote up but I think I still lack reputation because I don't see any symbol on every comment. but big thanks to you and to everyone who helped! :) @user3284463

Comment: @louie click the tick mark next to the answer

Comment: i don't see any tick mark on here (?) @user3284463

Comment: The tick mark will be under the vote count of the answer(not comment). @louie

Comment: i don't see it when i hover your answer :/ @user3284463

Comment: Hmm, perhaps this will help: http://i.imgur.com/Q3A1XbU.png @louie

Comment: i was so stupid. i'm sorry. i know where it is lol apologies sir. hope u can help me with my new problem :(( but thanks a lot for helping me out on the previous one! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `id` parameter instead of the function `view_id`. Also, there is a typo in your URL `==`. Your code should look something like this:

```
function view_id(id)
    {
      if(confirm('Are you sure you want to accept this member request? '))
      {
        window.location='acceptRequest.php?view_id='+id;

      }
    }
```

You seem to have a typo in you SQL near `members(id,`. It is good practice to also mention the columns needed in your SQL. You can leave the id slot and let MySQL do the increment by itself. Also, you should put your PHP code in a if statement to stay on the safe side:

```
$firstname = $row['firstname'];
$MI = $row['MI'];       
$lastname = $row['lastname'];  
$gender = $row['gender'];
$status = $row['status'];
$maiden = $row['maiden'];
$bday = $row['bday'];
$contactno = $row['contactno'];
$email = $row['email'];    

$insert_sql=mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO members (firstname, MI, lastname, gender, status, bday, contactno, email) 
                                      VALUES ('$firstname','$MI','$lastname','$gender','$status','$bday','$contactno','$email')");

if($insert_sql){
  mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM requests WHERE id=".$_GET['view_id']);
  header("Location: pendingrequests.php");
}
```

Comment: you had the same idea with the other smart person up there. you guys are genius! thank you! :)

Comment: hi sir, it's me again. idk what happen but the data like name, contact no, etc are not being inserted in the member table. i thought i did it awhile ago but i was wrong, only the id in that table ib being incremented but the values of the fields like name are not inserting. i have the same code as you.

Comment: omg i just realized that you are the same person as who i'm talking to in the comments lol, anyway, i think my mistake is here -> `$sql = "SELECT * FROM requests WHERE id=".$_GET['view_id'];` but i already added this -> `$row = mysqli_query($sql);` but values like name, status, etc are still not inserting in the members table, but the id increments. i can't figure out what's wrong because there's no error either :(

Comment: try `echo "<pre>"; print_r($row); echo "</pre>";`  and check you are getting the values

Comment: I'm having this error `Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given`

Comment: it's finally working now, all is well. thank you so much for the help awhile ago :)

Comment: That is great! Sorry I wasn't able to help. Was away from my PC @louie

Comment: It's okay. You were already a big help with my previous problems. Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

This is your javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function view_id(id)
    {
      if(confirm('Are you sure you want to accept this member request? '))
      {
        window.location='acceptRequest.php?view_id=='+view_id;

      }
    }
</script>
```

You pass a parameter into this function and it is called `id` but in the body of this script you use a non existant variable called `view_id`

Change

```
window.location='acceptRequest.php?view_id=='+view_id;
```

To

```
window.location='acceptRequest.php?view_id='+id;
```

Also note I changed `==` to `=` in that line

Also this statement is wrong

```
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO members 
                    (id,'$firstname','$MI','$lastname','$gender',
                    '$status','$bday','$contactno','$email')");
```

I would suggest leaving the `id` out as if that is an `auto increment` column it will be created automatically and you do not need to pass a value.

```
mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO members VALUES
                    ('$firstname','$MI','$lastname','$gender',
                    '$status','$bday','$contactno','$email')");
```

Alternatively if it is not an `auto increment` column you will need to create a variable called `$id` and change the query syntax to use `$id` and not `id`.

Ok if it still does not work you need to get an erro message from `mysqli` like this. In fact you should always be checking the status of all calls to the `mysqli` api.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO members VALUES
                    ('$firstname','$MI','$lastname','$gender',
                    '$status','$bday','$contactno','$email')");

if ( $result === FALSE ) {
    echo 'Insert ERROR: ' . mysqli_error($conn);
    exit;
}
```

This should report back to the page what the error was in your query.

I notice that you capture `$maiden = $row['maiden'];` but you dont use that in the query! Could it be that that column is set to require a value and that is why the query is failing? Or that missing that column out completely means that the columns that follow `maiden` are being loaded into columns that are not compatible with the data they are now recieving.

In my opinion it is better to use this longer but more precise syntax

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO members                  
                               (colname,colname,colname,colname,
                                colname,colname,colname,colname,)
                               VALUES
                             ('$firstname','$MI','$lastname','$gender',
                              '$status','$bday','$contactno','$email')");
```

Then at least you are always going to get the correct data loaded into the correct column name.

Comment: I've already solved this sir, but thank you anyway :) It finally deletes from my requests table but it didn't insert in my members table.

Comment: See additional fix for your INSERT query

Comment: Yes sir, id is an auto increment. I already removed the id from my insert query but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, third try, add some error checking and you will get told what is wrong with the query.